# How to handle loader state for the initial render as initial state of loader is false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For the initial render loader is not visible so how to make it visible  in react js by loader state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in your main app.js file

```js
  function App() {
     const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
     useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);
      fetch('api/v1/data')
      .then(() => setLoading(false));
     })
     return (
       <div className="App">
         <div>
           <Loader isLoading={isLoading}/>
           <MainComponent/>
         </div>
      </div>
}
```

I recently wrote a util with a bit different technique of maintaining loader state in an app which I find more convenient. Take a look [here](https://github.com/lokeshpathrabe/loader-util)